# Authenticate for Azure REST API without login

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0

I have a backend process that doesn't directly interact with the user. I want to access reservations associated with my Azure account but I'm having trouble with the authentication step. I was following the guide [here](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2017/03/03/azure-rest-api-with-certificate-and-service-principal-by-silent-backend-daemon-service/comment-page-1/?unapproved=30119&moderation-hash=1f5999c956a07c303c8bd751f6e53369#comment-30119) and I managed to get the authentication request to work by calling

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-ID}/oauth2/token
```

as a POST with the following x-www-form-urlencoded body:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&
client_id={client-ID}&
client_secret={client-Secret}&
resource=http://myapp42
```

However, when I attempt to call:

```
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/{order-ID}/reservations/{reservation-ID}?api-version=2019-04-01
```

with the bearer token I received during the authentication step, I get the following error message:

> The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource 'http://myapp42'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/', 'https://management.core.windows.net', 'https://management.azure.com/', 'https://management.azure.com'

However, if I modify the resource on the request to be one of these, `http://management.core.windows.net/` for instance, the authentication then fails with:

> AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F was not found in the tenant named {tenant-ID}. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: b54cedea-3804-41cf-bd27-fcf0ed1c4700\r\nCorrelation ID: 2371d375-6c89-4f05-83c9-c4629b3340a8\r\nTimestamp: 2020-02-05 01:59:57Z

How do I authenticate so that I can then get my reservations without having to login?

**Update:**
The service principal has both the Owner and Contributor roles assigned.

**Update 2:**
Thanks to @Jim Xu, I was realized that I needed to refrain from url-encoding the URL. That allowed me to get the access token with a value of `https://management.azure.com/` for the `resource` field. However, at this point, when I attempt to call the REST API with the resulting bearer token, I get the following error:

> The client '{Object-ID}' with object id '{Object-ID}' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/reservations/read' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/{order-ID}/reservations/{reservation-ID}' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials

Note: The object ID returned by this error is the one associated with the service principal.

**Update 3:**
I checked the reservation and it seems that the principal does not have a role in that reservation's access control. However, I also cannot assign the principal a role because it does not show when I search for principals during the role-assigning process.

Comment: Could you please tell me if the reservation  and the  sp  are in the same Azure AD tenant?

Comment: It looks that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call Azure Rest API to get the information of reservation Orders, you need to assign Owner\Contributor  for the service principal.(the action needs `Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/read` permission).

The steps are as below

1. Get access token

```
POST : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-ID}/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&
client_id={client-ID}&
client_secret={client-Secret}&
resource=https://management.azure.com/ or https://management.core.windows.net
```

[image]

2. Call the api

```
GET : https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/reservationOrders/{order-ID}/reservations/{reservation-ID}?api-version=2019-04-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

For more details, please refer to the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754635/does-the-azure-reserved-vm-instances-reservationorders-work-at-all) and the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796861/authentication-with-azure-management-api/57799725#57799725)

---

## update

If you have assigned role but you still cannot get access token, please try to encode your url.

Comment: but its not about his permissions? its about not being able to obtain a token?

Comment: So, I thought this wasn't a solution until I noticed that you hadn't url-encoded the value. After URL-encoding the value, I got the token

Comment: @Woody1193 Could you please tell me which type of your subscription? CSP or Pay-As-You-Go subscription (MS-AZR-0003P or MS-AZR-0023P)?

Comment: It's a CSP client subscription

Comment: @Woody1193 If your subscription is CSP, the Azure reservation is managed by your CSP provider. The customer cannot manage it.

Comment: @JimXu I was afraid that would be the case :(